# If $ j , k , n$ are consecutive integers and $jn$ has last digit $9$, what is the last digit of $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$ j , k , n$ are consecutive integers such that $0 < j < k < n$ and the units (ones) digit of the product $jn$ is $9$, what is the units digit of $k$?

SAT Question. I don't know if we are to use trial-and-error or what?

Comment: Hint: having odd product, both $\,j\,$ and $\,n=j+2\,$ are odd, and coprime to $\, 5,\,$ so few cases remain. Alternatively, $\,{\rm mod}\ 10\!:\,\ j(j+2)\equiv 9 \iff (j+1)^2\equiv 0\ \ $

Comment: Trial-and-error is surprisingly fast here given that every should know the multiplication table of single digit numbers. If you have studied congruences and such that helps more (you can take full advantage of Bill's hint). I don't remember at what level SAT comes, so cannot make a guess, whether the students might have been exposed to congruences at the point.

Answer (score 2):

Let the unit digits be $x_j, x_k, x_n$.  Then $x_j x_n \equiv 9 \pmod {10}$ (why?) $\implies (x_j, x_n) \in \{(1, 9), (3, 3), (7,7),(9, 1)\}$.

Given the consecutive condition, $n-j=2$, so what do you think $x_k$ could be?

Comment: Not always, for example $17*17=289$.

Comment: @PeterHorvath missed that case.

Comment: Sorry, thank you the extension.